# cols does not work in tags$textarea of a Shiny application

Tags: r, textarea, shiny

In the following code example. 
cols does not work in tags$textarea.

```
library(shiny)
# Global variables can go here
# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
tags$textarea(id="foo", rows="10", cols="4000", "Default value")
)
# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
}
# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How to copy with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Bootstrap has defined the width for `<textarea>` (206px), and you will have to override the Bootstrap style, e.g.

```
tags$textarea(id="foo", rows="10", style="width:800px;", "Default value")
```